# How to scroll the page with rjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

How can I scroll the page to a partial, which got inserted via rjs?

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :comments, :partial => 'comment', :object => @comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a javascript method to your page and call it from your controler

for ex:- In your example.html.erb

```
function scrollToDiv(id){
     // This method is used to scroll page 
}
```

And in your controller method

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :comments, :partial => 'comment', :object => @comment
page << "scrollToDiv('#{@comment.id}')"
```